# Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects Error

Tags: python, web-scraping

This code worked fine a few weeks ago and now I'm getting this reindexing error. Any idea how to fix this? I looked at some of the other threads where this error occurred but I have no idea what went wrong. These are the error below that I'm receiving. Thanks

Error Received

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jkru0\OneDrive\Desktop\Other\Other\Feb 5 py\finviz.py", line 38, in <module>
    df = scrape_finviz_data(version)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\jkru0\OneDrive\Desktop\Other\Other\Feb 5 py\finviz.py", line 34, in scrape_finviz_data
    return pd.concat(data).reset_index(drop=True)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jkru0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 393, in concat
    return op.get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jkru0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 676, in get_result
    indexers[ax] = obj_labels.get_indexer(new_labels)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jkru0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3874, in get_indexer
    raise InvalidIndexError(self._requires_unique_msg)
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
PS C:\Users\jkru0\OneDrive\Desktop\Other\Other\Feb 5 py>
```

Full Code

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import bs4
import time
import random
import xlsxwriter

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'
}

def scrape_finviz_data(version):
    url = f'https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v={version}&r={{page}}&f=all&c=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70&f=ind_stocksonly&o=-marketcap'

    page = 1

    screen = requests.get(url.format(page=page, version=version), headers=headers)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(screen.text, features='lxml')
    pages = int(soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'screener-pages'})[-1].text)

    data = []
    for page in range(1, pages + 1, 20):
        print(version, page)
        screen = requests.get(url.format(page=page, version=version), headers=headers).text
        tables = pd.read_html(screen)
        tables = tables[-2]
        tables.columns = tables.iloc[0]
        tables = tables[1:]
        # Reset the index of each DataFrame
        tables = tables.reset_index(drop=True)
        data.append(tables)
        time.sleep(random.random())
    
    return pd.concat(data).reset_index(drop=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    version = '152'
    df = scrape_finviz_data(version)

    # Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("finviz.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

    # Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

    # Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

    # Write the column headers with the defined format.
    for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
        worksheet.write(0, col_num, value)

    # Save the Excel file.
    writer.save(
```

)

New Errors

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\jkru0\OneDrive\Desktop\vince.py", line 35, in 
df = scrape_finviz_data(version)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "c:\Users\jkru0\OneDrive\Desktop\vince.py", line 27, in scrape_finviz_data
tables = pd.read_html(StringIO(screen))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\jkru0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1245, in read_html
return _parse(
^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\jkru0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1008, in _parse
raise retained
File "C:\Users\jkru0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 988, in _parse
tables = p.parse_tables()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\jkru0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 248, in parse_tables
tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\jkru0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 603, in _parse_tables
raise ValueError("No tables found")
ValueError: No tables found
PS C:\Users\jkru0\OneDrive\Desktop>

Comment: The error indicates that your index values aren't unique, i.e. there are duplicate values. Whichever field in the data you're using for the index probably introduced a duplicate value recently, and now the error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the issue in the dataframe column manipulation in each iteration. Leave the columns as they are and then the `.concat` succeeds:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
}


def scrape_finviz_data(version):
    url = f"https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v={version}&r={{page}}&f=all&c=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70&f=ind_stocksonly&o=-marketcap"

    page = 1

    screen = requests.get(url.format(page=page, version=version), headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(screen.text, features="lxml")
    pages = int(soup.find_all("a", {"class": "screener-pages"})[-1].text)

    data = []
    for page in range(1, pages + 1, 20):
        # print(version, page, url.format(page=page, version=version))
        screen = requests.get(
            url.format(page=page, version=version), headers=headers
        ).text
        tables = pd.read_html(StringIO(screen))
        data.append(tables[-2])

    return pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    version = "152"
    df = scrape_finviz_data(version)
    print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
   No. Ticker                Company                  Sector                        Industry Country Market Cap     P/E Fwd P/E   PEG    P/S    P/B    P/C   P/FCF Dividend Payout Ratio   EPS EPS this Y EPS next Y EPS past 5Y EPS next 5Y Sales past 5Y EPS Q/Q Sales Q/Q Outstanding   Float Insider Own Insider Trans Inst Own Inst Trans Float Short  Short Ratio     ROA      ROE     ROI Curr R Quick R LTDebt/Eq Debt/Eq Gross M  Oper M Profit M Perf Week Perf Month Perf Quart Perf Half Perf Year Perf YTD  Beta   ATR Volatility W Volatility M   SMA20   SMA50  SMA200 50D High 50D Low 52W High 52W Low    RSI from Open    Gap Recom Avg Volume  Rel Volume   Price  Change    Volume  Earnings Target Price    IPO Date
0    1   AAPL              Apple Inc              Technology            Consumer Electronics     USA   2676.73B   28.77   26.11  3.89   6.97  44.45  42.84   26.51    0.56%       14.72%  5.95     -0.84%      8.22%      21.57%       7.40%        12.16%   5.42%    -1.40%      15.94B  15.62B       0.09%        -2.36%   61.00%     -0.47%       0.69%         1.84  28.23%  160.09%  59.84%   0.98    0.92      1.63    1.81  43.45%  29.23%   24.68%    -2.05%     -8.76%    -11.73%     5.45%    14.26%   31.77%  1.29  3.58        2.05%        1.90%  -3.73%  -5.78%   3.08%  -13.18%   2.14%  -13.63%  37.88%  38.25    -0.41%  0.71%  1.87     58.40M        0.88  171.21   0.30%  51619727  Aug 03/a       181.08  12/12/1980
1    2   MSFT  Microsoft Corporation              Technology       Software - Infrastructure     USA   2345.95B    32.6   24.95  2.26  11.07  11.38  21.08   39.44    0.90%       28.09%  9.68     12.02%     15.15%      35.37%      14.40%        14.05%  20.59%     8.34%       7.43B   7.32B       1.51%        -0.15%   72.21%      0.47%       0.56%         1.66  18.63%   38.82%  26.14%   1.77    1.75      0.34    0.39  68.92%  41.77%   34.15%    -0.40%     -3.97%     -7.28%    11.16%    30.98%   31.66%  0.91  6.04        1.52%        1.68%  -3.33%  -3.72%   6.74%  -11.79%   2.04%  -13.91%  47.94%  39.38    -0.71%  1.39%  1.41     24.74M        0.97  315.75   0.67%  24075210  Jul 25/a       392.78   3/13/1986
2    3   GOOG           Alphabet Inc  Communication Services  Internet Content & Information     USA   1662.50B   27.89   19.67  1.52   5.77   6.23  14.05   23.38        -        0.00%  4.73     24.39%     18.20%      38.33%      18.40%        20.89%  19.05%     7.63%       6.00B   5.01B      60.25%        -0.02%   28.04%          -       0.67%         1.55  16.51%   23.33%  20.76%   2.17    2.14       0.1    0.11  55.38%  26.08%   21.15%     0.46%     -3.71%      8.99%    30.13%    30.88%   48.60%  1.06  2.84        2.28%        1.84%  -2.67%  -0.09%  17.26%   -5.77%  11.09%   -5.77%  58.00%  45.93    -1.57%  0.62%  1.46     21.84M        1.06  131.85  -0.96%  23210644  Jul 25/a       149.97   3/27/2014
3    4  GOOGL           Alphabet Inc  Communication Services  Internet Content & Information     USA   1650.01B   27.68    19.5  1.50   5.73   6.19  13.94   23.21        -        0.00%  4.73     24.47%     18.21%      38.33%      18.40%        20.89%  19.05%     7.63%       5.96B   5.91B      53.14%        -0.02%   36.87%     -0.21%       0.78%         1.64  16.51%   23.33%  20.76%   2.17    2.14       0.1    0.11  55.38%  26.08%   21.15%     0.47%     -3.69%      9.32%    29.71%    30.79%   48.32%  1.05  2.89        2.31%        1.90%  -2.76%  -0.33%  17.03%   -5.96%  10.69%   -5.96%  57.02%  45.56    -1.85%  0.77%  1.45     28.14M        1.09  130.86  -1.10%  30807599  Jul 25/a       150.04   8/19/2004
4    5   AMZN        Amazon.com Inc.       Consumer Cyclical                 Internet Retail     USA   1304.30B  101.09   40.15     -   2.42   7.78  20.22  406.45        -            -  1.26          -     43.05%           -           -        24.02%       -    10.85%      10.24B   8.99B      12.40%        -0.03%   60.30%      0.61%       0.89%         1.50   2.91%    8.71%   4.25%   0.95    0.70      0.82    0.91  45.53%   3.53%    2.43%    -1.55%     -5.89%     -2.49%    24.63%     7.72%   51.33%  1.24  3.66        2.85%        2.53%  -6.52%  -5.68%  12.52%  -12.85%   3.32%  -12.85%  56.11%  37.26    -0.73%  1.65%  1.24     53.53M        1.16  127.12   0.90%  61986572  Aug 03/a       173.67   5/15/1997
```

Comment: I posted the errors I'm getting at the bottom of my original post.  Not sure if I had to install String IO?

Comment: @user3444610 It seems that pandas was unable to find table in some pages. You can handle this condition by using `try ... except` for example.

Comment: It worked now. Nice